Salesforce Rest API to delete all where
I have a list of custom object records that are related to an account id.  I would like to periodically delete all the records with accountId='xyz'.
currently I am doing an SOQL to get all records with that accountId, and then deleting each result individually.
is there a way to "DELETE ALL where AccountId='xyz'".  I cant use batch jobs, because I have other scripts that run based on these deletes.

Going by the minimal information from your question, you can do the following:

Create a Scheduled Trigger Flow
Add a Start Date and Time and set the Frequency to Once (assuming you want to run it every day)
Add a Delete Records element with the filters Account__c ='xyz'


